# General function to get the frequency of certain word in a string

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to get a frequency of specific word from some text. Then use this function to calculate the frequency of selected word for each row in the data frame.

So far, what I am doing is creating a function that takes the input of a string and a pattern (i.e. str, pattern). Since `grep` captures all the patterns in the string, I felt `length` would take care of the job of capturing the frequency of the selected pattern.

```
word_count = function(str,pattern) {
   string = gsub("[[:punct:]]","",strsplit(str," "))
   x = grep("pattern",string,value=TRUE)
   return(length(x))
 }
```

For data frame(my_df) it looks like this:

```
id                      description
123  "It is cozy and pretty comfy. I think you will have good time 
     here."
232  "NOT RECOMMENDED whatsover. You will suffer here."
3333 "BEACHES are awesome overhere!! Highly recommended!!"

...so forth(more than obs.15000)
```

I have actually made all the description portion to lower case, so it is actually more like this:

```
id                      description
123  "it is cozy and pretty comfy. i think you will have good time 
     here."
232  "not recommended whatsover. you will suffer here."
3333 "beaches are awesome overhere!! highly recommended!!"

...so forth(more than obs.15000)
```

Then what I really want to my function to do:

```
word_count(my_df$description[1],recommended)
[1] 0 

word_count(my_df$description[3],highly)
[1] 1
```

But what it is doing:

```
word_count(my_df$description[1],recommended)
[1] 2 

word_count(my_df$description[3],highly)
[1] 2
```

It is essentially returning wrong answer. Hopefully, I want to use this function to apply on all the rows in the data frame, and I am planning on doing so by using `if`. However, while testing for individual rows, it doesn't seem to do the job I want.

Comment: In your `word_count ` function for `grep`  why have you quoted `"pattern"`, it should be without quotes.

Comment: I was actually hoping R to understand it like when I input `word_count(str,hello)`, it would be understood as `grep("hello",..)` so that I didn't have to put double quotations every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the function to

```
word_count = function(str,pattern) {
   sum(grepl(pattern, strsplit(str, " ")[[1]]))
}
```

We first the split the string on empty space (`" "`) then search for `pattern` in every word using `grepl`. As `grepl` returns `TRUE`/`FALSE` values to count the number of times a `pattern` occurred we can directly use `sum`.

Then when you try the function it will return you the expected output.

```
word_count(df$description[1],"recommended")
#[1] 0
word_count(df$description[3],"highly")
#[1] 1
```

---

However, note that there is `str_count` function in `stringr` which can give you directly the number of occurrences for every row

```
stringr::str_count(df$description, "recommended")
#[1] 0 1 1
```